# Convert VBA to VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm copying data form one workbook to another workbook and then run a macro from the copied workbook. The below VBA code works fine.

**VBA Code**

```
Sub test()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\work_data.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\other_work_data.xlsm")

    x.Sheets("myworksheet").UsedRange.Copy

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    y.Save
    x.Close

    Application.Run ("other_work_data.xlsm!checkDate")

    y.Close

End Sub
```

Now, I'm trying to change the following `vba` code to `vbscript`, but it doesn't work for me.

**VBScript code**

```
Sub test()

    Dim ExcelApp
    Dim x
    Dim y

    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set x = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\work_data.xlsx")
    Set y = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\other_work_data.xlsm")

    x.Sheets("myworksheet").UsedRange.Copy

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    y.Save
    x.Close

    ExcelApp.Application.Run ("other_work_data.xlsm!checkDate")

    y.Close

    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ExcelApp.Application.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Since I'm new to `vba` and `vbscript`, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I had gone through similar questions in stack overflow, but I didn't sort out the issue.

Comment: How does it not work? How far does it get? what error occurs? (Try passing .run a full path)

Comment: @AlexK. I didn't get any error. Also tried with full path in .run. Data didn't get copy from one book to another book.

Comment: Do you need the additional `Application` statements after the `ExcelApp` references? ExcelApp is already set as an application. Try removing the `Application` from `ExcelApp.Application.Run ("other_work_data.xlsm!checkDate")` and `ExcelApp.Application.Quit`

Comment: Are you sure you specified the correct sheets? Does this work: `x.Sheets("myworksheet").UsedRange.Copy y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` I assume not saving after running the macro is deliberate?

Comment: @Rory yeah I specified the correct sheets...

Comment: @JordanBiddlecombe Tried removing `Application` from `.Run` and `.Quit` but again remains the same.

Comment: before `.copy` you could add `ExcelApp.visible = true` to see if Excel is opening. You could add some `MsgBox "stop to check"` to stop action and check if everything is going ok at that stage of the macro. Or temporary `Exit sub` somewhere in the middle to test temp process results.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. *What* "doesn't work"? How *exactly* does it "not work"? Is your application not opening? Are changes not saved? What result do you expect, and how is the result you're actually getting different from that? As KazimierzJawor mentioned, running the application visible should be your first step when debugging. Also, don't set `DisplayAlerts` to `False` while troubleshooting, as that might hide the issue.

Comment: remove the parenthesis from the argument in `.Run`. `other_work_data.xlsm!` is also unnecessary, I believe.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It's unnecessary, but is unlikely to cause problems here, because in this context it's interpreted as "pass the argument (the string) by value".

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone. Sorted out the problem. Done a small mistake. I didn't call the `subroutine test()`. @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had sorted out the problem. Actually, the problem is very simple. I used the subroutine `test()` and I forgot to call. So, I had used `Call test()`.

```
Sub test()

Dim ExcelApp
Dim x
Dim y

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\work_data.xlsx")
Set y = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\other_work_data.xlsm")

x.Sheets("myworksheet").UsedRange.Copy

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

y.Save
x.Close

ExcelApp.Run ("other_work_data.xlsm!checkDate")    'ExcelApp.Run is enough

y.Close

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelApp.Quit                                      'ExcelApp.Quit is enough
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

End Sub

Call test()
```

Otherwise, it also works without writing the code inside subroutine

```
Dim ExcelApp
Dim x
Dim y

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\work_data.xlsx")
Set y = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\mywork\other_work_data.xlsm")

x.Sheets("myworksheet").UsedRange.Copy

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

y.Save
x.Close

ExcelApp.Run ("other_work_data.xlsm!checkDate")    'ExcelApp.Run is enough

y.Close

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelApp.Quit                                      'ExcelApp.Quit is enough
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

Thanks for everyone helped me through comments. Thanks for your time.